# How to Remove related products for the particular product with sku or id?

Tags: magento2, related-products, cross-sells, up-sells

I need to remove All the Related products for the particular product with Id. I referred and got the SQL query to do that. Can this achieve by Model & Resource Model? Any help is appreciated.

> delete from catalog_product_link where product_id in (15) and
> link_type_id=1;

[Answer found in Stack which using direct SQL query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/333124/86103)

Answer (score 1):

After a struggle Managed to do it myself! Sharing the Answer might help others.

```php
class Example
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function removeRelatedLinks($sku)
    {

        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        $links = $product->getProductLinks();
        if (count($links)) {
            foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
                if ($link->getLinkType() === 'related') {
                    unset($links[$key]);
                }
            }
            $product->setProductLinks($links);
            $this->productRepository->save($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great information :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do is by below script code. You need to load product object by SKU or ID.

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$productObject = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', 'Test Test');
$linkDataAll = [];

$existingRelatedProducts = $product->getProductLinks();

if($existingRelatedProducts) {
    $product->setProductLinks($linkDataAll);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: This will remove all the links to product, including Up sell & Cross Sells.

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, I needed to remove all **related** and **up-sell** products for all products. So I've made a shell script:

Here is my class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Product\Console\Command;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Exception;
class UnlinkProducts extends Command
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private State $state;

    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('vendor:unlink-products');
        $this->setDescription('Unlink related, cross and up sells products');

        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

        $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        // $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('sku','my_sku');
        foreach ($productCollection as $product){
            $linkedProducts = $product->getProductLinks();
            if (count($linkedProducts) > 0){
                echo $product->getSku().PHP_EOL;
                foreach ($linkedProducts as $key => $linked){
                    if ((string) $linked->getLinkType() === 'related' || (string) $linked->getLinkType() === 'upsell'){
                        unset($linkedProducts[$key]);
                    }
                }

                $product->setProductLinks($linkedProducts);
                try{
                    $product->save($product);
                }catch(Exception $error){
                    echo $error->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        $output->writeln('Done!');
    }
}
```

Now if you run : `bin/magento vendor:unlink-products`, it should work. Don't forget to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` before.

Good Luck!